# Undefined values in directive Angularjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive with data who comes from ajax call, my problem is the data is undefined when the directive is created because ajax is still loading, I know with a setTimeout to validate this and use $scope.apply() it could be works, but it doesn't seems a good approach and also try to add $watch to flag ajaxLoading but it doesn't works.

```
pmApp.directive("filter", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            ngModel: '=',
            display: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "views/template.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var value = attrs.value,
                scopeParent = scope.$parent,
                model = attrs.ngModel;

            scope.description = attrs.description;
            scope.value = value;

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                scope.ngModel = scope.data[0][value];
                scope.$apply();
            }, 2000);


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where is your ajax call?

Comment: Add a watch on the data object that is filled by the ajax call. Since you are using isolated scopes you need to pass the data object that is filled using ajax.

Comment: @Chandermani How can I the pass the data object?

Comment: You are already passing it in `data` variable. See if a `watch` on `data` works inside directive. What is the structure of your data object?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever method you use for that ajax call, it should return a promise. Save this promise on your controller and pass it in the directives scope configuration, so that the directive can access it.

Now you can use the promise, to delay your variable assignment, instead of `setTimeout`.

But as a general recommendation, you should use the builtin [`$timeout` Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) instead of `setTimeout`, so you don't have to worry about digest cycles. For detailed information visit https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq.